# How do I prevent Capistrano from running composer install with --no-dev?

Tags: capistrano, composer-php

I currently have the following:

```
namespace :deploy do

    desc "Build"
    after :updated, :build do
        on roles(:app) do
            within release_path  do
                execute :composer, "install --quiet" # install dependencies
                execute :chmod, "u+x artisan" # make artisan executable
            end
        end
    end
```

Running `cap development deploy` ends up showing:

`INFO[d2c5a027] Running /usr/bin/env composer install --no-dev --prefer-dist --no-interaction --quiet --optimize-autoloader`

How come it's not using the command I'm providing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According https://github.com/capistrano/composer you can override the defaults.

```
set :composer_install_flags, '--no-dev --no-interaction --quiet --optimize-autoloader'
```

Comment: When you are using Capifony with Symfony, you should use `composer_options` instead of `composer_install_flags` (see [Capifony Cookbook](http://capifony.org/cookbook/composer-vendors.html)).  Like this: `set :composer_options, '--no-interaction --quiet --optimize-autoloader --no-progress'`

Answer (score 0):

In my composer it is

```
set :composer_options, '--my  --options'
```